# About making a video for pre-presentation of the PhD Thesis for the Master Judge

Tags: phd, thesis, presentation

I was in **one PhD Thesis Presentation Ceremony** last week and have seen some **aggressive Attack** from one of **the judge masters** to **the Student which had presented its PHD thesis**.

I guess some part of this situation has been done by **prejudging** the student works and not having **enough time for reading the content of thesis** and having **too much question about the thesis** which could not be **possible for asking during that one meeting**.

So I have seen the **MSC student presenting their seminar** by recording one 15 minutes video about their power point of their seminar and **uploading** it at some video host like **YouTube**, so  I have one **suggestion** for **our faculty**, **by doing this process** as one Pre-Presentation for the PhD Thesis **Presentation Ceremony process**, too.

This work would help the masters to better **review and understanding** the student thesis and **save many of their time** for reading the huge papers of one PHD thesis, also it would help them to **remove unnecessary question** and ask **better question** for helping **the student to make their final presentation better**.

if possible I like to have **your comment** about the suggestion of:

> - giving a PRE PRESENTATION  PhD Thesis Presentation Ceremony  by a recorded video to the Master Judge .

Thanks.

Comment: The somewhat random bold formatting of this post seems to make it a lot harder, rather than easier, to read. My tendency is to pause and yell out each bold section.

Answer (score 3):

I have some worries, to be honest. It is hard to make a firm recommendation without knowing something about personalities, but such a thing *could* backfire.

First is the question of whether anyone in the target group would actually watch it. Those with an interest in it or who were closely aligned with the ideas, might, but someone who isn't going to take a deep dive into the written work may not bother.

Second, watching a video doesn't give the opportunity to ask questions at the moment and it might be possible for a viewer to reach misconceptions of the work. It might lead to more questions or, in the worst case, more hostile questions. But that is a personality matter.

I would look for some evidence that this has been actually tried successfully before attempting it. And evidence from my own field. Some research into the effectiveness of such things might be required.

If you make such a video, I'd strongly suggest that you get feedback on it from a few people you trust. Unfortunately, that can make the creation a long and involved effort.

Another thing to consider is what your advisor thinks and the role that they play in the defense. In my own case, one of the  members was from a different sub field and admitted to me after the (successful) defense that he didn't really know enough of the background to be able to offer much help, though he gave a positive "vote". But that was at least in part because he could depend on the reputation of my advisor that everything was "solid". In fact, it is a fairly common practice for committee members to ask the advisor to assure them that "all is well."

I hope that aggressive attacks are rare and I suspect that they depend on personalities - or even departmental conflicts. Even large mathematics departments can be very political with various factions constantly at war. But a video presentation isn't going to save anyone from that. Maybe the opposite. "To the barricades!!!"